# a question about improper integral, I cannot solve it!

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

If $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$, and $\displaystyle\int_c^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx$ is convergent for any $c>0$. Please prove $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}\, dx = f(0) \ln \frac{\beta}{\alpha}$.

This is my solution:

Suppose $\displaystyle\int_A^{B}\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}\, dx=\int_A^B \frac{f(\alpha x)}{x} \, dx-\int_A^B \frac{f(\beta x)}{x} \, dx$.

And then we can suppose $u=\alpha x$ and $u=\beta x$.

Thus $\displaystyle\int_{\alpha A}^{\beta B} \frac{f(u)}{u} \, du-\int_{\alpha A}^{\beta B} \frac{f(u)}{u} \, du$. Also we can let $A \rightarrow 0$ and $B\rightarrow \infty$. But I cannot prove the question using this method.

I mean is there something wrong with my method? Or my method cannot apply to the question?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$! I applied the markup pretty much verbatim here. Indicate any egregious transcription errors on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x} = \int_{\beta}^{\alpha} du \, f'(u x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your method does not work for this question because when you split up the original integral into the difference of two integrals, those new integrals may not converge.  As an example, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$.  The integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x(1+\alpha x)}\,dx$$ (and similarly for $\beta$) does not converge because of the singularity at 0.  However, the difference
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{1+\alpha x} - \frac{1}{1+\beta x}}{x}\, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta-\alpha}{(1+\alpha x)(1+\beta x)}\,dx$$ converges, because the singularity at 0 has been cancelled out by the subtraction.